# sum of column values in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to calculate the sum of value in anagularjs.

1) In Textbox if I enter 2, it should multiply with 2000 and the result will be **4000**.

2) In second row id I enter 3 it should multiply with 100 and the result will be **300**.

2) Same as in third row id I enter 4 it should multiply with 50 and the result will be **200**.

3) So **4000+300+200 = 4500** result should come in total place.

Multiply is working fine. But how to calculate the total amount here. And If I ger **4500** value, is this possible to show the amount in words like **"Four Thousand Five Hundrad"**

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3">Details of Cash</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cash Notes</td>
    <td>Amount in Rs.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="amount" id="textBox2">X 2000</td>
    <td>{{ (+amount) * 2000}}</td>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="amount3" id="textBox2">X 100</td>
    <td>{{ (+amount3) * 100}}</td>
    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="amount4" id="textBox2">X 50</td>
    <td>{{ (+amount4) * 50}}</td>
    
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td>{{total}}</td>
    
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Share you complete code in PLunkr on how you have implemented. I dont think you can have ""Four Thousand Five Hundrad"

Answer (score 0):

Add some kind of **watcher** on your variables and re-calculate the total when they change. I would use `ng-change` for this. Then simply call a common function for that. Here is a demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.calcTotal = function() {
    $scope.total = ($scope.amount || 0) * 2000 + ($scope.amount3 || 0) * 100 + ($scope.amount4 || 0) * 50;
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <table>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="3">Details of Cash</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cash Notes</td>
        <td>Amount in Rs.</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" ng-change="calcTotal()" ng-model="amount" id="textBox2">X 2000</td>
        <td>{{ (+amount) * 2000}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" ng-change="calcTotal()" ng-model="amount3" id="textBox2">X 100</td>
        <td>{{ (+amount3) * 100}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" ng-change="calcTotal()" ng-model="amount4" id="textBox2">X 50</td>
        <td>{{ (+amount4) * 50}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td>{{total}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```